# Whitebox GIS installation on linux

Tags: installation, java, linux, whitebox-gat

I am installing [Whitebox](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) GIS software on linux.

I have already:

1. set up a clean xfce4 machine
2. installed java 8 successfully
3. unzipped the latest version of whitebox ([Iguazu 3.2.1](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml)) to the desktop

Whenever I click on the JAR file or try to run through  terminal nothing happens.

Am I missing some key dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been quite some time since I've used Linux, but I seem to recall two general ways of launching Java programs.

1. It can be launched from the command line as you would on any other system:

> java -jar /full-path-to/WhiteboxGIS.jar

2. Navigate to the Whitebox folder. Right click the WhiteboxGIS.jar and select 'Properties'. Mark the file as executable (i.e. set the executable bit). You may have to associate the jar extension with Java on your system, if it isn't already. After this point, you should be able to launch it by double-clicking WhiteboxGIS.jar as you would normally.

Comment: I was installing on a remote machine with only 512KB RAM. This is why it did not work. Scaled up and everything works perfectly!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it. I haven't heard of a computer with only 512KB (MB?) of RAM in a very, very long time!

Comment: oops. 512Mb. Now I have access to 64Gb.... should be good

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Solved it by installing openjdk-jre-8, then running

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

which gave me this (yours may be different):

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

so now I could cd into my WhiteboxGAT dir and run

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar WhiteboxGIS.jar
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Great answer, thanks, it worked for me.