# How to run WhiteboxGis under linux system only with command lines or terminals?

Tags: installation, linux, whitebox-gat

I have to run the Whitebox on Linux system, but I am new to use Linux. Therefore, I do not know how to run the whitebox software on Linux. The followings are what I tried to run the software:

```
~/Desktop/rhessys/Whitebox_3_2_1$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
~/Desktop/rhessys/Whitebox_3_2_1$ ls
lib  logs  README.TXT  ReleaseNotes.txt  resources  WhiteboxGIS.jar
~/Desktop/rhessys/Whitebox_3_2_1$ java -jar  WhiteboxGIS.jar
~/Desktop/rhessys/Whitebox_3_2_1$
```

After typing "java -jar WhiteboxGIS.jar", the software was no response. Or it was running? If it is running how can put data into the whitebox to calculate?

Comment: What Linux OS are you trying to run Whitebox GAT on?

Comment: And give the suggestions from this answer a shot too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116904/1297

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried what you suggested. I typed the commands in terminal, but it looked like same with what I have posted.  By the way, how to figure out which type of Linux? I am using a network of high performance computers.

Answer (score 2):

For the text message in your command line, I can observe the last java version ("1.8.0_31"; recommended for the last version of Whitebox GAT 'Iguazu' v. 3.2.1) and the correct unziped directory (Whitebox_3_2_1). However, the suitable command to launch the program is:

```
java -jar "WhiteboxGIS.jar"
```

as it is in the README.txt file y not:

```
"java -jar WhiteboxGIS.jar"
```

as it is written  in your message.

On the other hand, is convenient that you previously run this command:

```
chmod +x WhiteboxGIS.jar
```

to ensure that 'WhiteboxGIS.jar' will be an executable file. Linux 'Flavor' is irrelevant in this context because **Whitebox GAT** was conceived as portable software; independently of the operative system.

In my GNU/Debian system, with 1.8.0_31 java version and in the Whitebox_3_2_1 directory ('Iguazu' version), I launched Whitebox with this command:

```
java -jar "WhiteboxGIS.jar"
```

and this was the result:

[image]

You may wish to place a shortcut to the .jar file on your desktop for easier access.

Comment: `chmod +x WhiteboxGIS.jar` is most likely they answer. But in some cases it would of helped to know the Linux OS because some distros have a package available for WhiteboxGAT.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. No matter which types of command line I typed, I got the same results. There was no above interface coming out. The followings are about the Linux OS:
LSB Version:base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Linux orc129 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux            I think may be I need to compile the codes of the software and then run it.  Am I right?

Comment: @Junting Guo Please, run the comand:`ls -l WhiteboxGIS.jar` and post the result.

Comment: @xunilk:[junting@orc129 Whitebox_3_2_1]$ ls -l WhiteboxGIS.jar                                                 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 junting icreed 1015939 Sep 18 19:06 WhiteboxGIS.jar

Comment: @Junting Guo: You have the privileges for running this software. It is very strange that you can not.

Comment: @Junting Guo: Please, close all programs and try to launch Whitebox GAT only.

Comment: @xunilk: I tried it, but it did not work.  Does someone use whitebox on linux without user interface? Or After typing: java -jar WhiteboxGIS.jar, what should I type? I mean where can I find commands for next step to enter in?

Comment: @Junting Guo: I installed java 1.8.0_31 in another Linux (Ubuntu 14.10), I copied the **Whitebox_3_2_1** directory from my Debian partition and I launched Whitebox GAT with double click in the .jar file. It worked fine too. Can you access to another Linux PC with java 1.8.x for testing this portable software? You can use one USB pendrive.

Comment: @xunilk: Yes, I can use another LINUX PC in my lab. However, I can not run the software in my computer. Anyway, Thank you a lot.